# How to create and execute .net web service clients?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl, asmx

I need to create and execute a C#.net client that consumes a web service (wsdl).

I have used the `wsdl.exe` tool:

```
wsdl.exe /language:CS /out:c:\myTests\ http://localhost:8080/myTestService.wsdl
```

getting as output a .cs file that contains several methods but no main.

How do I create a client that invokes the remote method of the web service?

Comment: What you have is a proxy.  You need to write the program that will use that proxy to communicate with the service.

Comment: The WSDL.EXE tool is part of the legacy ASMX technology. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN. See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with no prejudice on why you ask this question and why are you implementing this thing of the past, you might want to try this :

```
var client = new myTestService();
var result = client.AvailableMethod();
```

hope this helps.

Comment: the AvailableMethod are two (let's say test() and testAsync()). The test() methods produces an internal server error on the glassfish server (javax.servlet.ServletException, java.lang.NoSuchMethodException) while the testAsync() method runs without problems but it returns a void. How do I get the result of the method invocation?